# Bookmark consecutive lines that have same specific value

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
ABC
GFGFG
/////////////////////////
ggtrgrh
htrhrth
nbtnyumjyumu
myuuykukyyuk
/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////
AAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAA
RET5t4yy
HTH^565y56y
/////////////////////////
tertet
/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////
```

now I want to bookmark consecutive lines that have `/////////////////////////`
this mean in above list only `three last lines` and lines between `myuuykukyyuk` and `AAAAA` must select by regex.
I tried following regex but not working for me:

```
(?:.*/{25,}\r?\n?){3}
^/*/{25,}$
```

where is my regex problem?

I want to only match two or more lines that only contain 25 or more slashes

Comment: Maybe you want to only match two or more lines that only contain 25 or more slashes? `^/{25,}(?:\R/{25,})+$`?

Comment: You are matching 4 lines now, and there are no 4 consecutive lines in your data that have only forward slashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, your regex is good and working for me - please send as answer that i can accept your answer.

Comment: Please update the question with the actual requirements (I mentioned them in my comment).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew check post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^/{25,}(?:\R/{25,})+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNfWE2/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `/{25,}` - twenty-five or more forward slashes
- `(?:\R/{25,})+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\R` - any line break sequence
  - `/{25,}` - twenty-five or more forward slashes
- `$` - end of a line

See the screenshot with demo and settings:

[image]